# React Typescript: Checkbox disabled using variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

`console.log(disabled)` is returning `true` but the `checkbox` is not getting disabled.

```
let disabled: boolean;

const GroupChange = (value) => {
   var index = dropdownItems.findIndex(item => item.group == value);
   ...

   disabled = dropdownItems[index].deactivated;
}
```

`Form` with the `Checkbox`:

```
<Form.Item label="Gruppe" name="group">
   <Select onChange={GroupChange}>
      {dropdownItems.map((item, index) => <Select.Option value={item.group} key={index}>{item.group}</Select.Option>)}
   </Select>
</Form.Item>

<Form.Item label="Aktiv" name="active" valuePropName="checked">
   <Checkbox disabled={disabled} /> //<- is always active 
</Form.Item>
...
```

Comment: what if you do `"disabled"` instead of `{disabled}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AntDesign, you use something called [`dependencies`](https://ant.design/components/form/#dependencies):

```
<Form.Item label="Gruppe" name="group">
   <Select>
      {dropdownItems.map((item, index) => <Select.Option value={item.group} key={index}>{item.group}</Select.Option>)}
   </Select>
</Form.Item>
<Form.Item dependencies={['group']}>
 {({getFieldValue}) => {
    const groupValue = getFieldValue('group')
    const isDisabled = dropdownItems.find(item => item.group === groupValue)?.deactivated
    return (
      <Form.Item label="Aktiv" name="active" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox disabled={isDisabled} />
      </Form.Item>
    )
 }}
</Form.Item>
```

You render a `Form.Item` with a `dependencies` prop. The child is a function that gets form methods as an argument and gets called whenever the values of the dependencies change.

You **DO NOT** need, `onGroupChange` anymore.